# db.replace(TABLE_INFO, null, values); not working

Tags: android, sqlite

The query is woking great for Inserting new items but it is not Replacing the old item, googled stuff but didnt got any solution.....

If it has something to do with with ID can anyone please help with a code snippet....

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you get any errors? please post some code!

Comment: ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(USER_ID, friends.get(i).getId());

values.put(USER_NAME, friends.get(i).getName());

db.replace(TABLE_INFO, null, values);

the code is something like this

Comment: No errors just replace query is not working properly....
Insertion is working properly

Comment: Show the table definition.

Comment: USER_ID is id(Primary key), USER_NAME contains name and TABLE INFO is the name of the table

Answer (score 0):

```
use update  query in place of replace
db.update(TABLE_INFO, null, values);
```